# How to construct the 2d structure in a dynamic fashion

Tags: ruby

I iterate through all cars and its supported attributes (many attributes per car) to create a structure like this, how do I do this in a dynamic fashion.

```
cars = {
   "honda" => {'color' => 'blue', 'type' => 'sedan'}.
   "nissan" => {'color' => 'yellow', 'type' => 'sports'}.
...
}

cars.each do |car|
   car_attrs = ...
   car_attrs.each do |attr|
     ??? How to construct the above structure
   end
end
```

Comment: just need pseudo code to achieve the above, what information do you need?

Comment: we need to know what structure has an object car. Also, it's confusing that you are using "cars" both as the desired output and the input.

Comment: cars doesn't have a structure, the structure mentioned above is the structure of the car. Not sure why would you down vote the question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... But i guess this is what you want:

```
cars = {}
options = {}
options['color'] = 'blue'
...
cars['honda'] = options
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Will I be able to do this cars['honda']['color] to print blue? I am unable to do this

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be asking for a way to create a 2-dimensional hash without having to explicitly create each child hash. One way to accomplish that is by specifying the default object created for a hash key.

```
# When we create the cars hash, we tell it to create a new Hash
# for undefined keys
cars = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new }

# We can then assign values two-levels deep as follows
cars["honda"]["color"] = "blue"
cars["honda"]["type"] = "sedan"
cars["nissan"]["color"] = "yellow"
cars["nissan"]["type"] = "sports"

# But be careful not to check for nil using the [] operator
# because a default hash is now created when using it
puts "Found a Toyota" if cars["toyota"]

# The correct way to check would be
puts "Really found a Toyota" if cars.has_key? "toyota"
```

Many client libraries assume that the [] operator returns a nil default, so make sure other code doesn't depend on that behavior before using this solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using something similar to ActiveRecord (but easy to modify if you are not):

```
cars_info = Hash[cars.map { |car| [car.name, car.attributes] }
```

Comment: @Jason. Well, it should be pretty similar in any case. Hash + map